# Are read-only CultureInfo objects thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, globalization, cultureinfo

*Preface:* I know how to create a read-only CultureInfo object. That is not the question and it has been answered in detail here:

- [CultureInfo thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3298491/87698)

Note that the text of that question is similar to this one, but the answers are completely different. Before thinking about closing this question as a duplicate of the other one, please consider the fact that *none* of the answers in the other question answers this question.

---

My question:

**Is it thread-safe to access instance members of a read-only CultureInfo object?**

Reasons to assume that it is:

- If it weren't, using instance members of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or objects retrieved by `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` wouldn't be thread-safe, and a lot of code would break.
- The community seems to think so (see [Henk's comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298594/87698)), but does not explain why.

Reasons to assume that it isn't:

- No such garantee is made in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) (*"Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."*)
- People often confuse "read-only" and "thread-safe", although [they are two different things.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different/)

Comment: The documentation pages always include a note about [thread safety](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) near the end. Did you check it? Besides, thread-safety is a concern only when modifying an object. It isn't a concern with read-only objects or when the only access is for reading

Comment: *Why* are you asking this question? Did you encounter a problem? As for MSDN, it *does* state that static members are thread safe. `InvariantCulture` *is* a static, as is `GetCultureInfo()`.

Comment: Finally, if you want a better explanation, just [check the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, I checked it, it contains just the default disclaimer. I've clarified that in the question. I know that *getting* InvariantCulture is static, but *accessing* `InvariantCulture.Calendar`, for example, is a *member access*, and, thus, not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Unless it's only for reading. Given that the source *is* available you can check it directly, but simply returning a value from a backing field *is* thread safe

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: True, but implementations might change. That's why "design by contract" exists. :-)

Comment: Yes, and in this case *reading* isn't supposed to change anything. In fact, you *could* argue that any field access method is not thread safe even if the code actually is, because someone may change it in the future to regenerate the field or something.

Comment: On the other hand, with open source code, the code *is* the contract.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: If you plan to never upgrade your libraries, sure. ;-) On a more serious note: I actually don't think closed/open source makes a difference here; design by contract is about the *division of responsibility* between user and library. If a method's contract states that it returns a list of user names (and nothing else), the library developer has the freedom to return them in a different order in the next version without telling anyone. If he decides to return a list of user objects instead, he breaks the contract and must declare this as a breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

Thread safety is an issue when you are altering an object, so the question is: are you altering the object or does something happen inside the `CultureInfo` that could change its state.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) isn't particularly clear about this: it just shows the default notice about thread-safety.

So we have to find out ourselves. Luckily, the `CultureInfo` class is made available through the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs). There you will find it will load the culture data at the start of the method, and cache that result inside the `CultureInfo` class.

The initialization of properties is not thread-safe. See for example the [`NumberFormat` property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1390): it can instantiate two instances due to concurrent calls. There is no locking!

There are more problems at some places, for example the `NumberFormat` property again, where you can change its properties. Inside that class it checks if it is writable or not, so if you are using default cultures (the read-only ones, like `InvariantCulture`) there is no thread-safety issue. In all other cases we can't assume it is thread-safe.

Conclusion: they are not thread-safe.

Comment: But it should be threadsafe, otherwise as the OP points out, you could never safely use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` since there is only one instance of it, and you'd never know if another thread (perhaps in an entirely separate class library) was using it. I suppose Microsoft could have made an egregious error with  `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, but I'm pretty sure they didn't, and accessing it is indeed threadsafe.

Comment: But that one is safe since you can't change its state. Its backing data is read-only. If you create your own `CultureInfo`, you could end up in trouble with multi-threading and lazy loading of `NumberFormat` for example. @MatthewWatson

Comment: Ah I see, your conclusion is talking about non-read-only CultureInfo. I was confused because the OP was asking only about read-only ones. To be clear, is your answer to the question "Is it thread-safe to access instance members of a read-only CultureInfo object?" `Yes`?

Comment: You could end up with two `NumberFormat` instances, but since they are read-only internally, there isn't an issue.

Comment: @MatthewWatson for your edited comment: basically yes, but not entirely since there could still be two instances of the same backing info.

Comment: @PatrickHofman NumberFormat probably *is* thread-safe for read-only CultureInfo objects.. The only modification is assigning a fully initialized object to the backing field. Even if this happens *twice*, the two objects will be identical as long as they are generated from the same m_CultureData field

Comment: They have the same fields but they are not identical. Comparing for equality is one thing that goes wrong @pan